# Showing weird output in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I try to pot time series data but the graph is coming wrong comparing tableu. Please find the photos attached.

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thI65.jpg)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thI65.jpg)

Comment: Please don't add code as an image.

Comment: Please also add reproducible test data as text (or code).